# How to get the date of a file without opening?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have locked files by one process and I need to get the date of that file from another process.

How can I do that without using CreateFile to open it to get a handle. (file is locked so this wouldn't work)

GetFileTime is done by using CreateFile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [stat()](http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/functions/unixio.html#stat). It works on the filename itself and doesn't require an open handle.

Comment: Considering you're on windows, here is a link to the MSDN for `stat`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stay within the pure Windows API, try [`GetFileAttributesExW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364946.aspx). I presume that function is what `stat` uses internally.

If you prefer the [`stat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx) functions, always make sure to use the `_wstat64` variant to get Unicode and 64-bit support.